# Как разбить данные одной ячейки list на несколько ячеек?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Основной DataFrame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это DataFrame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разбить столбец 0 с объектом list на два столбца со своим названием 0,1?

Чтобы в итоге получился такой DataFrame (цифры для образца там другие):

[image]

Как получаю такой результат с DataFrame-List:

```
    # Original column's names.
    INDEX_COL = 0
    NAME_COL = "name"
    SEX_COL = "sex"
    PCLASS_COL = "passengerClass"
    AGE_COL = "age"
    SURVIVED_COL = "survived"

    # New column's names.
    AGE_GROUP_COL = "AgeGroup"
    age_by_survived = df.groupby([AGE_GROUP_COL, SURVIVED_COL])
    age_by_survived
    <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f4d168decd0>
    age_by_survived = age_by_survived.size().unstack()
    age_by_survived_without_na = age_by_survived[1:].fillna(0)
    def map_to_percent(r):
      return [float(v)/sum(r) for v in r]

    z = age_by_survived_without_na.apply(map_to_percent, axis=1)
    z = z.to_frame().reset_index()
```

Comment: Гораздо проще не создавать столбец со списками, чем потом разбивать его на два ;). Как вы создаете данный столбец?

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы проценты получить в колонках 0,1

Comment: можете выложить ваш датасет на какой-нибудь свободный файлообменник?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ImiUD_jISFYPfnx9_phhNR3w1bTF3-Gr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: я уже привел пример с __оригинальным__  датасетом Titanic - алгоритм действий такой же...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с использованием [стандартного `Titanic` датасета (от Kaggle)](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data):

читаем данные:

```
In [158]: url = r"C:\download\data\titanic\train.csv"

In [159]: df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

train DataFrame:

```
In [160]: df
Out[160]:
     PassengerId  Survived  Pclass                                               Name     Sex  ...  Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin  Embarked
0              1         0       3                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  ...      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN         S
1              2         1       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  ...      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85         C
2              3         1       3                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  ...      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN         S
3              4         1       1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  ...      0            113803  53.1000  C123         S
4              5         0       3                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  ...      0            373450   8.0500   NaN         S
..           ...       ...     ...                                                ...     ...  ...    ...               ...      ...   ...       ...
886          887         0       2                              Montvila, Rev. Juozas    male  ...      0            211536  13.0000   NaN         S
887          888         1       1                       Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith  female  ...      0            112053  30.0000   B42         S
888          889         0       3           Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"  female  ...      2        W./C. 6607  23.4500   NaN         S
889          890         1       1                              Behr, Mr. Karl Howell    male  ...      0            111369  30.0000  C148         C
890          891         0       3                                Dooley, Mr. Patrick    male  ...      0            370376   7.7500   NaN         Q

[891 rows x 12 columns]
```

столбцы:

```
In [161]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[161]:
['PassengerId',
 'Survived',
 'Pclass',
 'Name',
 'Sex',
 'Age',
 'SibSp',
 'Parch',
 'Ticket',
 'Fare',
 'Cabin',
 'Embarked']
```

создаем столбец `AgeGroup`:

```
In [162]: df["AgeGroup"] = df["Age"] // 10 + 1

In [163]: df[["Sex", "Age", "AgeGroup", "Survived"]]
Out[163]:
        Sex   Age  AgeGroup  Survived
0      male  22.0       3.0         0
1    female  38.0       4.0         1
2    female  26.0       3.0         1
3    female  35.0       4.0         1
4      male  35.0       4.0         0
..      ...   ...       ...       ...
886    male  27.0       3.0         0
887  female  19.0       2.0         1
888  female   NaN       NaN         0
889    male  26.0       3.0         1
890    male  32.0       4.0         0

[891 rows x 4 columns]
```

создаем DF с разбивкой по "AgeGroup":

```
In [165]: z = df.groupby("AgeGroup")["Survived"].mean().reset_index(name="SurvPct")

In [167]: z["NonSurvPct"] = 1 - z["SurvPct"]
```

Результат:

```
In [168]: z
Out[168]:
   AgeGroup   SurvPct  NonSurvPct
0       1.0  0.612903    0.387097
1       2.0  0.401961    0.598039
2       3.0  0.350000    0.650000
3       4.0  0.437126    0.562874
4       5.0  0.382022    0.617978
5       6.0  0.416667    0.583333
6       7.0  0.315789    0.684211
7       8.0  0.000000    1.000000
8       9.0  1.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо